# Is there a software solution for LPT port emulation?

Tags: printing, simulation, dos, lpt

Is there a **software solution for simulating a printer for an old program** under DOS or an old Windows (type 98 or XP), which sends a text stream through the LPT port to the printer, intercepts this stream and redirects it to a text file?

This is a matter of software imitation, the programming language, I think, does not play a role in the program itself.

Does even an LPT port software emulator exist?

Comment: There are printer drivers that create a virtual LPT port and use a file (PDF or "pure text") as a destination instead of a physical printer. But why are you looking for a way to write to LPT, just to intercept and redirect to a file, instead of directly writing to the file?